# Web file manager for s3 with DB folder structure in PhP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a solution to an application need. I need a web-based file manager/explorer that works with Amazon S3 buckets. The problem with most potential solutions I have found is that they are somehow relying on the s3 to maintain the directory hierarchy. This is bad because it means additional latency when traversing folders (and listing their contents).

What I would like is a php app/class that maintains the directory structure (and filenames) in a database, so that listing/traversing files and directories is quick and the s3 is only accessed when actually downloading or uploading a file.

Does anyone know of anything like this? I'm hoping there is something already in existence rather than taking the time to build from scratch.

Thanks!

Comment: @E_p I spent lots of time searching google and I can't find one that meets the specific requirements I outlined in my message. Did you read beyond the title?

Comment: Just personal opinion that relying on the S3 to maintain the directory, listing/traversing files and directories is currently the best approach yet. By using only database the data will not be reliable anymore since the files/directories can still be managed via AWS management console or other apps.

Comment: @SubRed I agree with you in most cases. This is not the intended way to use s3. However, in my specific case I can restrict s3 writes/deletes to be handled by the web-app and all but eliminate the risks you described. The performance in listing files on s3 is important for this particular project so a DB driven solution is important. I think I'll end up rolling my own solution, and if it goes well I may open-source it and post a link to the source as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd definitely recommend using [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette).

It abstracts away the filesystem, so you're able to switch between local storage, FTP, SFTP, S3 etc simply by switching the Adapter